# How can I update Laravel from 8.78 to 8.79 without getting my other files deleted?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have just learned laravel and done half of my new project. I currently have laravel version 8.78.1 installed and I am facing an error that is due to a bug.
This bug is solved in version 8.79 ( https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.79.0 ).

My question is How can I update Laravel from 8.78 to 8.79 without getting my other files deleted?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why would it delete your files?

Comment: Just run `composer update`, it updates the files in the vendor folder only.

Comment: Thank you so much @aynber, That is what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, I have laravel version 8.62, but when I run composer update, the whole project has been deconfigured, luckily I have made a backup, how can I update only the core of laravel to the latest version 8.75?

Answer (score 1):

Run `composer update laravel/framework`, which will only update Laravel as you want, and nothing else will change besides your Laravel vendor files.